# Replace Open/Save dialog

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, save-as, dialog, open

Is it possible to make an own save/open dialog (through windows app development) and hook it in to replace the normal save/open dialog?

I'm pretty sure it's not possible through the normal UI/Win10 settings, but what about registry changes and/or replacing a DLL?

Note that I'm talking about completely replacing it - not just changing or adding icons.

I'd to make something similar to the image below. I understand this is not the best for everyone, but for me it will save **a lot** of clicking per day.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible unless you do some pretty heavy hacking. To open these dialogs you make calls to the WinApi. Somehow you would need to replace WinApi components to be able to do it with all the issues that this action could rise.

So summarizing I would say that this is not possible if you want to do it in a reliable manner.

Comment: On a side note, why would you like to modify the dialog? To change the apparence or to add different functionality?

Comment: I've updated the Question with a picture that I have in mind. Note that this might not be for everyone the best thing, but for me it would **really** improve my workspeed.

Comment: I see. Unfortunatelly that's not possible. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

I've done custom "file save as" dialogs through DLL function hooking in Windows 7. If you google search apihijack_src.zip it contains a good C++ demo for function hooking with MS Visual Studio.

Usually you just need to intercept these function calls and create your own dialog box that returns the appropriate data. Unless the target application is disabling DLL function hooking.

- `COMDLG32.GetOpenFileNameW`
- `COMDLG32.GetSaveFileNameW`

The previous replies are true, though. Changing `COMDLG32.DLL` to include your custom `GetSaveFileName` might be difficult.

Comment: We really don’t like answers that say “Google X”. Please provide *the actual answer* in your post. (The middle part of what you have now is a good start.) If that requires copying a little bit from another web site, that’s OK, as long as you identify the source (by name and link). If it’s too long to copy (or there are legal restrictions on copying), then at least provide an actual link to the page that contains the answer (i.e., *not* just a Google search).